# Execute PHPUnit when is installed as part of a project

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have added composer to a standalone project as:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.*"
    }
}
```

After I run `composer require "phpunit/phpunit=5.4.*" --dev` the libraries gets installed under `vendor/`. I have write a small test case and I put it under `tests/CollectionTest.php` and I want to run it but ....

```
# phpunit
bash: phpunit: command not found

# phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests
bash: phpunit: command not found
```

I have also added this:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/
```

to `~/.bash_rc` file. Did I miss something? How do I execute the test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit is installed in `vendor` folder in your project directory rather than in global directory. Try to `cd` into your projects directory and run the PHPUnit by:

```
$ cd /{project-directory}
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Detailed test setup can be configured with the [phpunit.xml file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should find an alias in the `bin` directory to the `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` path. So try:

```
>bin/phpunit
```

or

```
>vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Hope this help